# RPM Signing verification fail in Ubuntu but works on CentOS

Tags: security, centos, digital-signature, rpm, gnupg

What could be causing the inconsistency in `rpm -Kv` hello.rpm recognizing the signature generated by my Python script that mimics the original singing process of the rpm tool?  The signature is successfully added to the rpm package, but sometimes the command fails to recognize it.

The exact same file, which was signed on Ubuntu with a Python script although whose signature was not recognised by the rpm tool, will be recognised if I move it to CenOS (Docker) and attempt to verify it there.

Any insights or suggestions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. I am using Ubuntu for the signing the rpm package using python script.

### On Ubuntu Machine

Command: `rpm -Kv hello.rpm`
Output:

```
hello.rpm:
    Header RSA signature: BAD (package tag 268: invalid OpenPGP signature)
    Header SHA256 digest: OK
    Header SHA1 digest: OK
    Payload SHA256 digest: OK
    MD5 digest: OK
```

Command: `rpm -qiv hello.rpm`
Output:

```
error: demo.rpm: Header RSA signature: BAD (package tag 268: invalid OpenPGP signature)
error: demo.rpm: not an rpm package (or package manifest)
```

### On CentOS Machine (Using Docker)

Command: `rpm -Kv hello.rpm`
Output:

```
hello.rpm:
    Header V4 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 80d9f118: OK
    Header SHA256 digest: OK
    Header SHA1 digest: OK
    Payload SHA256 digest: OK
    MD5 digest: OK
```

Command: `rpm -qiv hello.rpm`
Output:

```
Name        : hello
Version     : 0.0.1
Release     : 1.el8
Architecture: noarch
Install Date: (not installed)
Group       : Unspecified
Size        : 34
License     : GPL
Signature   : RSA/SHA256, Sat May  6 10:39:43 2023, Key ID af325bfe80d9f118
Source RPM  : hello-0.0.1-1.el8.src.rpm
Build Date  : Wed Jan 25 06:43:19 2023
Build Host  : e5eee6689554
Relocations : (not relocatable)
Summary     : A simple hello world script
Description :
A demo RPM build
```

Here are the further details from rpm trace

Command: `RPM_TRACE=1 rpm -qip hello.rpm` 
Output:

### On Ubuntu Machine

```
_rpmInitCrypto: entered
_rpmInitCrypto: -> success
_rpmDigestInit: entered
_rpmDigestInit: ctx: returning 0x55801d8f9b50
_rpmDigestInit: -> success
_rpmDigestInit: entered
_rpmDigestInit: ctx: returning 0x55801d8f9b30
_rpmDigestInit: -> success
_rpmDigestUpdate: entered
_rpmDigestUpdate: ctx: &mut <- 0x55801d8f9b50
_rpmDigestUpdate: data: &[] <- 0x7f3135667160
_rpmDigestUpdate: -> success
_rpmDigestUpdate: entered
_rpmDigestUpdate: ctx: &mut <- 0x55801d8f9b30
_rpmDigestUpdate: data: &[] <- 0x7f3135667160
_rpmDigestUpdate: -> success
_rpmDigestUpdate: entered
_rpmDigestUpdate: ctx: &mut <- 0x55801d8f9b50
_rpmDigestUpdate: data: &[] <- 0x7ffc410f5b70
_rpmDigestUpdate: -> success
_rpmDigestUpdate: entered
_rpmDigestUpdate: ctx: &mut <- 0x55801d8f9b30
_rpmDigestUpdate: data: &[] <- 0x7ffc410f5b70
_rpmDigestUpdate: -> success
_rpmDigestUpdate: entered
_rpmDigestUpdate: ctx: &mut <- 0x55801d8f9b50
_rpmDigestUpdate: data: &[] <- 0x55801d900ea8
_rpmDigestUpdate: -> success
_rpmDigestUpdate: entered
_rpmDigestUpdate: ctx: &mut <- 0x55801d8f9b30
_rpmDigestUpdate: data: &[] <- 0x55801d900ea8
_rpmDigestUpdate: -> success
_rpmDigestUpdate: entered
_rpmDigestUpdate: ctx: &mut <- 0x55801d8f9b50
_rpmDigestUpdate: data: &[] <- 0x55801d901008
_rpmDigestUpdate: -> success
_rpmDigestUpdate: entered
_rpmDigestUpdate: ctx: &mut <- 0x55801d8f9b30
_rpmDigestUpdate: data: &[] <- 0x55801d901008
_rpmDigestUpdate: -> success
_rpmDigestDup: entered
_rpmDigestDup: ctx: & <- 0x55801d8f9b50
_rpmDigestDup: -> success
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: ctx: owned <- 0x55801d8f9b50
_rpmDigestFinal: -> success
_rpmDigestDup: entered
_rpmDigestDup: ctx: & <- 0x55801d8f9b30
_rpmDigestDup: -> success
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: ctx: owned <- 0x55801d8f9b30
_rpmDigestFinal: -> success
_rpmDigestDup: entered
_rpmDigestDup: ctx: & <- 0x55801d8f9b50
_rpmDigestDup: -> success
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: ctx: owned <- 0x55801d8f9b30
_rpmDigestFinal: datap: Option<&mut> <- 0x7ffc410f5ab0
_rpmDigestFinal: lenp: Option<&mut> <- 0x7ffc410f5ab8
_rpmDigestFinal: -> success
_rpmDigestDup: entered
_rpmDigestDup: ctx: & <- 0x55801d8c5c50
_rpmDigestDup: -> success
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: ctx: owned <- 0x55801d8f9b30
_rpmDigestFinal: datap: Option<&mut> <- 0x7ffc410f5ab0
_rpmDigestFinal: lenp: Option<&mut> <- 0x7ffc410f5ab8
_rpmDigestFinal: -> success
_pgpDigParamsFree: entered
_pgpDigParamsFree: -> success
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: -> error: Failure: ctx must not be NULL
_pgpDigParamsFree: entered
_pgpDigParamsFree: -> success
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: -> error: Failure: ctx must not be NULL
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: ctx: owned <- 0x55801d8f9b50
_rpmDigestFinal: -> success
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: ctx: owned <- 0x55801d8c5c50
_rpmDigestFinal: -> success
_pgpDigParamsFree: entered
_pgpDigParamsFree: -> success
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: -> error: Failure: ctx must not be NULL
_pgpDigParamsFree: entered
_pgpDigParamsFree: -> success
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: -> error: Failure: ctx must not be NULL
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: -> error: Failure: ctx must not be NULL
_pgpPubkeyKeyID: entered
_pgpPubkeyKeyID: pkt: &[] <- 0x55801d8d4540
_pgpPubkeyKeyID: Key ID: 48EA1457D3E3330E
_pgpPubkeyKeyID: keyid: &[] <- 0x7ffc410f5d00
_pgpPubkeyKeyID: -> success
_pgpPrtParams: entered
_pgpPrtParams: pkts: &[] <- 0x55801d8d4540
_pgpPrtParams: paramsp: &mut <- 0x7ffc410f5cf0
_pgpPrtParams: PgpDigParams { obj, signid: buffer, userid: userid }: returning 0x55801d8d27a0
_pgpPrtParams: -> success
_pgpPrtParamsSubkeys: entered
_pgpPrtParamsSubkeys: pkts: &[] <- 0x55801d904e00
_pgpPrtParamsSubkeys: subkeys: &mut <- 0x7ffc410f5cf0
_pgpPrtParamsSubkeys: subkeys_count: &mut <- 0x7ffc410f5ce8
_pgpPrtParamsSubkeys: Got 0 subkeys
_pgpPrtParamsSubkeys: -> success
_rpmDigestInit: entered
_rpmDigestInit: ctx: returning 0x55801d8f9b50
_rpmDigestInit: -> success
_rpmDigestInit: entered
_rpmDigestInit: ctx: returning 0x55801d905c70
_rpmDigestInit: -> success
_rpmDigestUpdate: entered
_rpmDigestUpdate: ctx: &mut <- 0x55801d8f9b50
_rpmDigestUpdate: data: &[] <- 0x7f3135667160
_rpmDigestUpdate: -> success
_rpmDigestUpdate: entered
_rpmDigestUpdate: ctx: &mut <- 0x55801d905c70
_rpmDigestUpdate: data: &[] <- 0x7f3135667160
_rpmDigestUpdate: -> success
_rpmDigestUpdate: entered
_rpmDigestUpdate: ctx: &mut <- 0x55801d8f9b50
_rpmDigestUpdate: data: &[] <- 0x7ffc410f5b70
_rpmDigestUpdate: -> success
_rpmDigestUpdate: entered
_rpmDigestUpdate: ctx: &mut <- 0x55801d905c70
_rpmDigestUpdate: data: &[] <- 0x7ffc410f5b70
_rpmDigestUpdate: -> success
_rpmDigestUpdate: entered
_rpmDigestUpdate: ctx: &mut <- 0x55801d8f9b50
_rpmDigestUpdate: data: &[] <- 0x55801d908858
_rpmDigestUpdate: -> success
_rpmDigestUpdate: entered
_rpmDigestUpdate: ctx: &mut <- 0x55801d905c70
_rpmDigestUpdate: data: &[] <- 0x55801d908858
_rpmDigestUpdate: -> success
_rpmDigestUpdate: entered
_rpmDigestUpdate: ctx: &mut <- 0x55801d8f9b50
_rpmDigestUpdate: data: &[] <- 0x55801d9089b8
_rpmDigestUpdate: -> success
_rpmDigestUpdate: entered
_rpmDigestUpdate: ctx: &mut <- 0x55801d905c70
_rpmDigestUpdate: data: &[] <- 0x55801d9089b8
_rpmDigestUpdate: -> success
_rpmDigestDup: entered
_rpmDigestDup: ctx: & <- 0x55801d8f9b50
_rpmDigestDup: -> success
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: ctx: owned <- 0x55801d8f9b50
_rpmDigestFinal: -> success
_rpmDigestDup: entered
_rpmDigestDup: ctx: & <- 0x55801d905c70
_rpmDigestDup: -> success
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: ctx: owned <- 0x55801d905c70
_rpmDigestFinal: -> success
_rpmDigestDup: entered
_rpmDigestDup: ctx: & <- 0x55801d905130
_rpmDigestDup: -> success
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: ctx: owned <- 0x55801d905c70
_rpmDigestFinal: datap: Option<&mut> <- 0x7ffc410f5ab0
_rpmDigestFinal: lenp: Option<&mut> <- 0x7ffc410f5ab8
_rpmDigestFinal: -> success
_rpmDigestDup: entered
_rpmDigestDup: ctx: & <- 0x55801d9050f0
_rpmDigestDup: -> success
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: ctx: owned <- 0x55801d905c70
_rpmDigestFinal: datap: Option<&mut> <- 0x7ffc410f5ab0
_rpmDigestFinal: lenp: Option<&mut> <- 0x7ffc410f5ab8
_rpmDigestFinal: -> success
_pgpDigParamsFree: entered
_pgpDigParamsFree: -> success
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: -> error: Failure: ctx must not be NULL
_pgpDigParamsFree: entered
_pgpDigParamsFree: -> success
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: -> error: Failure: ctx must not be NULL
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: ctx: owned <- 0x55801d905130
_rpmDigestFinal: -> success
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: ctx: owned <- 0x55801d9050f0
_rpmDigestFinal: -> success
_pgpDigParamsFree: entered
_pgpDigParamsFree: -> success
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: -> error: Failure: ctx must not be NULL
_pgpDigParamsFree: entered
_pgpDigParamsFree: -> success
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: -> error: Failure: ctx must not be NULL
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: -> error: Failure: ctx must not be NULL
_pgpPubkeyKeyID: entered
_pgpPubkeyKeyID: pkt: &[] <- 0x55801d900ea0
_pgpPubkeyKeyID: Key ID: F1BAB259E14FA44E
_pgpPubkeyKeyID: keyid: &[] <- 0x7ffc410f5d00
_pgpPubkeyKeyID: -> success
_pgpPrtParams: entered
_pgpPrtParams: pkts: &[] <- 0x55801d900ea0
_pgpPrtParams: paramsp: &mut <- 0x7ffc410f5cf0
_pgpPrtParams: PgpDigParams { obj, signid: buffer, userid: userid }: returning 0x55801d903f80
_pgpPrtParams: -> success
_pgpPrtParamsSubkeys: entered
_pgpPrtParamsSubkeys: pkts: &[] <- 0x55801d90bcc0
_pgpPrtParamsSubkeys: subkeys: &mut <- 0x7ffc410f5cf0
_pgpPrtParamsSubkeys: subkeys_count: &mut <- 0x7ffc410f5ce8
_pgpPrtParamsSubkeys: Subkey: 27640070E2297392
_pgpPrtParamsSubkeys: dig: returning 0x55801d910500
_pgpPrtParamsSubkeys: Got 1 subkeys
_pgpPrtParamsSubkeys: -> success
_pgpDigParamsSignID: entered
_pgpDigParamsSignID: dig: & <- 0x55801d910500
_pgpDigParamsSignID: SignID: 27640070E2297392
_pgpDigParamsSignID: -> success
_rpmDigestInit: entered
_rpmDigestInit: ctx: returning 0x55801d8f9b50
_rpmDigestInit: -> success
_rpmDigestInit: entered
_rpmDigestInit: ctx: returning 0x55801d905600
_rpmDigestInit: -> success
_rpmDigestUpdate: entered
_rpmDigestUpdate: ctx: &mut <- 0x55801d8f9b50
_rpmDigestUpdate: data: &[] <- 0x7f3135667160
_rpmDigestUpdate: -> success
_rpmDigestUpdate: entered
_rpmDigestUpdate: ctx: &mut <- 0x55801d905600
_rpmDigestUpdate: data: &[] <- 0x7f3135667160
_rpmDigestUpdate: -> success
_rpmDigestUpdate: entered
_rpmDigestUpdate: ctx: &mut <- 0x55801d8f9b50
_rpmDigestUpdate: data: &[] <- 0x7ffc410f5b70
_rpmDigestUpdate: -> success
_rpmDigestUpdate: entered
_rpmDigestUpdate: ctx: &mut <- 0x55801d905600
_rpmDigestUpdate: data: &[] <- 0x7ffc410f5b70
_rpmDigestUpdate: -> success
_rpmDigestUpdate: entered
_rpmDigestUpdate: ctx: &mut <- 0x55801d8f9b50
_rpmDigestUpdate: data: &[] <- 0x55801d910848
_rpmDigestUpdate: -> success
_rpmDigestUpdate: entered
_rpmDigestUpdate: ctx: &mut <- 0x55801d905600
_rpmDigestUpdate: data: &[] <- 0x55801d910848
_rpmDigestUpdate: -> success
_rpmDigestUpdate: entered
_rpmDigestUpdate: ctx: &mut <- 0x55801d8f9b50
_rpmDigestUpdate: data: &[] <- 0x55801d9109a8
_rpmDigestUpdate: -> success
_rpmDigestUpdate: entered
_rpmDigestUpdate: ctx: &mut <- 0x55801d905600
_rpmDigestUpdate: data: &[] <- 0x55801d9109a8
_rpmDigestUpdate: -> success
_rpmDigestDup: entered
_rpmDigestDup: ctx: & <- 0x55801d8f9b50
_rpmDigestDup: -> success
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: ctx: owned <- 0x55801d8f9b50
_rpmDigestFinal: -> success
_rpmDigestDup: entered
_rpmDigestDup: ctx: & <- 0x55801d905600
_rpmDigestDup: -> success
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: ctx: owned <- 0x55801d905600
_rpmDigestFinal: -> success
_rpmDigestDup: entered
_rpmDigestDup: ctx: & <- 0x55801d905130
_rpmDigestDup: -> success
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: ctx: owned <- 0x55801d905600
_rpmDigestFinal: datap: Option<&mut> <- 0x7ffc410f5ab0
_rpmDigestFinal: lenp: Option<&mut> <- 0x7ffc410f5ab8
_rpmDigestFinal: -> success
_rpmDigestDup: entered
_rpmDigestDup: ctx: & <- 0x55801d902690
_rpmDigestDup: -> success
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: ctx: owned <- 0x55801d905600
_rpmDigestFinal: datap: Option<&mut> <- 0x7ffc410f5ab0
_rpmDigestFinal: lenp: Option<&mut> <- 0x7ffc410f5ab8
_rpmDigestFinal: -> success
_pgpDigParamsFree: entered
_pgpDigParamsFree: -> success
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: -> error: Failure: ctx must not be NULL
_pgpDigParamsFree: entered
_pgpDigParamsFree: -> success
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: -> error: Failure: ctx must not be NULL
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: ctx: owned <- 0x55801d905130
_rpmDigestFinal: -> success
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: ctx: owned <- 0x55801d902690
_rpmDigestFinal: -> success
_pgpDigParamsFree: entered
_pgpDigParamsFree: -> success
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: -> error: Failure: ctx must not be NULL
_pgpDigParamsFree: entered
_pgpDigParamsFree: -> success
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: -> error: Failure: ctx must not be NULL
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: -> error: Failure: ctx must not be NULL
_pgpPubkeyKeyID: entered
_pgpPubkeyKeyID: pkt: &[] <- 0x55801d8d4540
_pgpPubkeyKeyID: Key ID: AF325BFE80D9F118
_pgpPubkeyKeyID: keyid: &[] <- 0x7ffc410f5d00
_pgpPubkeyKeyID: -> success
_pgpPrtParams: entered
_pgpPrtParams: pkts: &[] <- 0x55801d8d4540
_pgpPrtParams: paramsp: &mut <- 0x7ffc410f5cf0
_pgpPrtParams: PgpDigParams { obj, signid: buffer, userid: userid }: returning 0x55801d901190
_pgpPrtParams: -> success
_pgpPrtParamsSubkeys: entered
_pgpPrtParamsSubkeys: pkts: &[] <- 0x55801d909500
_pgpPrtParamsSubkeys: subkeys: &mut <- 0x7ffc410f5cf0
_pgpPrtParamsSubkeys: subkeys_count: &mut <- 0x7ffc410f5ce8
_pgpPrtParamsSubkeys: Got 0 subkeys
_pgpPrtParamsSubkeys: -> success
_pgpPrtParams: entered
_pgpPrtParams: pkts: &[] <- 0x55801d9126b8
_pgpPrtParams: paramsp: &mut <- 0x55801d906da8
_pgpPrtParams: -> error: Failure: Signature Packet
_rpmDigestInit: entered
_rpmDigestInit: ctx: returning 0x55801d90f4b0
_rpmDigestInit: -> success
_rpmDigestInit: entered
_rpmDigestInit: ctx: returning 0x55801d909430
_rpmDigestInit: -> success
_rpmDigestUpdate: entered
_rpmDigestUpdate: ctx: &mut <- 0x55801d90f4b0
_rpmDigestUpdate: data: &[] <- 0x7ffc410f5d70
_rpmDigestUpdate: -> success
_rpmDigestUpdate: entered
_rpmDigestUpdate: ctx: &mut <- 0x55801d909430
_rpmDigestUpdate: data: &[] <- 0x7ffc410f5d70
_rpmDigestUpdate: -> success
_rpmDigestUpdate: entered
_rpmDigestUpdate: ctx: &mut <- 0x55801d90f4b0
_rpmDigestUpdate: data: &[] <- 0x55801d9140d8
_rpmDigestUpdate: -> success
_rpmDigestUpdate: entered
_rpmDigestUpdate: ctx: &mut <- 0x55801d909430
_rpmDigestUpdate: data: &[] <- 0x55801d9140d8
_rpmDigestUpdate: -> success
_rpmDigestDup: entered
_rpmDigestDup: ctx: & <- 0x55801d90f4b0
_rpmDigestDup: -> success
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: ctx: owned <- 0x55801d90f4b0
_rpmDigestFinal: -> success
_rpmDigestDup: entered
_rpmDigestDup: ctx: & <- 0x55801d909430
_rpmDigestDup: -> success
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: ctx: owned <- 0x55801d909430
_rpmDigestFinal: -> success
_rpmDigestDup: entered
_rpmDigestDup: ctx: & <- 0x55801d9050f0
_rpmDigestDup: -> success
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: ctx: owned <- 0x55801d909430
_rpmDigestFinal: datap: Option<&mut> <- 0x7ffc410f5d40
_rpmDigestFinal: lenp: Option<&mut> <- 0x7ffc410f5d48
_rpmDigestFinal: -> success
_rpmDigestDup: entered
_rpmDigestDup: ctx: & <- 0x55801d912610
_rpmDigestDup: -> success
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: ctx: owned <- 0x55801d909430
_rpmDigestFinal: datap: Option<&mut> <- 0x7ffc410f5d40
_rpmDigestFinal: lenp: Option<&mut> <- 0x7ffc410f5d48
_rpmDigestFinal: -> success
error: demo.rpm: Header RSA signature: BAD (package tag 268: invalid OpenPGP signature)
_pgpDigParamsFree: entered
_pgpDigParamsFree: -> success
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: -> error: Failure: ctx must not be NULL
_pgpDigParamsFree: entered
_pgpDigParamsFree: -> success
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: -> error: Failure: ctx must not be NULL
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: ctx: owned <- 0x55801d9050f0
_rpmDigestFinal: -> success
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: ctx: owned <- 0x55801d912610
_rpmDigestFinal: -> success
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: -> error: Failure: ctx must not be NULL
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: -> error: Failure: ctx must not be NULL
_pgpDigParamsFree: entered
_pgpDigParamsFree: -> success
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: -> error: Failure: ctx must not be NULL
_pgpDigParamsFree: entered
_pgpDigParamsFree: -> success
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: -> error: Failure: ctx must not be NULL
_rpmDigestFinal: entered
_rpmDigestFinal: -> error: Failure: ctx must not be NULL
error: demo.rpm: not an rpm package (or package manifest)
_pgpDigParamsFree: entered
_pgpDigParamsFree: -> success
_pgpDigParamsFree: entered
_pgpDigParamsFree: -> success
_pgpDigParamsFree: entered
_pgpDigParamsFree: -> success
_pgpDigParamsFree: entered
_pgpDigParamsFree: -> success
_rpmFreeCrypto: entered
_rpmFreeCrypto: -> success
```

### On CentOS Machine (Using Docker)

```
Name        : hello
Version     : 0.0.1
Release     : 1.el8
Architecture: noarch
Install Date: (not installed)
Group       : Unspecified
Size        : 34
License     : GPL
Signature   : RSA/SHA256, Sat May  6 10:39:43 2023, Key ID af325bfe80d9f118
Source RPM  : hello-0.0.1-1.el8.src.rpm
Build Date  : Wed Jan 25 06:43:19 2023
Build Host  : e5eee6689554
Relocations : (not relocatable)
Summary     : A simple hello world script
Description :
A demo RPM build
```

Found this [link](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/rpm/issues/2351) with the same problem but not able to understand what is the fix there.

Comment: does the ubuntu env have your gpg pub key installed?

Comment: yes @mask8. I have imported the same pubkey in both place in gpg keyring and rpm keyring in both OS.

Answer (score 0):

The referenced issue concludes that this can happen when you use something (go crypto) that produces output that OpenPGP cannot parse.

Sign the package with `rpmsign`.

Comment: Actually that works with the rpmsign. However, I want it to be done for some other reasons. Also, I have compaired the hex of both packages, singed by "rpmsign" and signed by python script and both looks the same.